# What is the best git strategy when producing a related product?

Tags: git

I have developed an application ApplicationA. It works well and it is git controlled. (i.e. it has a master branch and several other branches).

Now, I have been asked to developed another application ApplicationB, that is closely related to the first one but that it will be released as another product. In other words, although sharing a lot of code, ApplicationB and ApplicationA are somehow independent. (I mean, ApplicationB is not a further development of ApplicationA)

What is the branch approach I should take to develop B from A? should I just forget the master branch, create a ProductB branch and treat that as the master of B? 
Or should I just forget about branching, copy and paste the code and treat it as a totally different application?

Answer (score 2):

Using different branches in the same repository for different projects is not adviseable from my experience.

If both projects share common code, but also have parts exclusive for the respective application, as it is in your case, a good approach is to isolate the shared code in a third repository that you include as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in your `AplicationA` and `ApplicationB` repositories.

Changes the common codebase will be tracked in the submodules' repository, and the other projects can independently reference certain versions of the submodule. Both projects can benefit from bugfixes in the common code and no copy paste ist needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very useful answer. I am checking how to do this